# Autocomplete / get suggestions only for the function parameters, when inside a function

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, autosuggest

I'm using Python and I'm on the Jupyter Notebook, although I also use PyCharm so advice for this one would also be appreciated.

Whenever I'm using a function, and I'd like to pass some arguments, I'd like to have suggestions only for the function parameters. Instead, what I get when I press tab, is a long list of irrelevant stuff. Basically, I'd like to press tab, and get a list like this:

```
data=  
kind=  
stat_func=  
color=  
...(etc.)
```

without having to look at the documentation and finding the right parameter name every time.

Is there a way to get this? If not, what workaround do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I think `Parameter Info` is what you're looking for: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html#view-parameter-info